# Where to find info on (polytime) approximability of various discrete optimization problems?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms, optimization, approximation-hardness

Where to find info on (polytime) approximability of  various discrete optimization problems?

Sorry if this is stupid,but is there a site or reference that keeps up to date info on approximability of various optimization problems?

Answer (score 4):

The following website seems to be no longer maintained, but it is still a useful resource because it covers many problems: [http://www.csc.kth.se/~viggo/problemlist/](http://www.csc.kth.se/%7Eviggo/problemlist/)

Answer (score 0):

The compendium from Crescenzi is the most complete that I am aware of, despite being pretty old now. You can also watch this more recent (still twelve years old) survey:

Vangelis Paschos.  An overview on polynomial approximation of NP-hard problems.
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00186549/document